# want 3 Button one for left rotation , second for right rotation of image and 3 for stop

Tags: javascript

Want 3 Button one for left rotation , second for right rotation of image and 3 for stop.

Sample code snippet.

```
var num = 0;
var images = ["images/1.jpg","images/2.gif","images/3.jpg", "images/4.jpeg"];
var len = images.length;(
function loop(){
  var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');
  // change to match images folder 
  var delayInSeconds = 10; 
  // set number of seconds delay 
  // list image names 
  // don't change below this line 
  var changeImage =function loop(){
  var len = images.length; 
  rotator.src = images[num++]; if (num == len) { num = 0; 
  } 
};
//(ram.value=="True"){
 setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 50);
 //} 
//else 
//{ 
//change.value ="False"; 
//} 
})();
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly the problem is you're facing, also your code could use some syntax highlighting to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like below.

```js
var num = 0;
window.direction = 1;
var images = [
 "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png",
 "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png",
 "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png",
 "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png"
 ];
var len = images.length;(
function loop(){
  var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');
  // change to match images folder 
  var delayInSeconds = 10; 
  // set number of seconds delay 
  // list image names 
  // don't change below this line 
  var changeImage =function loop(){
  if(direction != -1) {
    var len = images.length; 
    rotator.src = images[direction ? num++ : num--];
    if (direction && num == len) { num = 0; }
    if (!direction && num == -1) { num = len-1; }
  }
};
setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 50);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="left" onclick="direction=1">Left</button>
<button id="right" onclick="direction=0">Right</button>
<button id="stop" onclick="direction=-1">Stop</button>
<br>
<img id="rotator">
```